# Fixed width integer types (e.g. uint32) in Python

Tags: python, integer, fixed-width

Certain mathematical operations, especially on data read from hardware drivers, can depend on fixed width of the data type. Example: bitwise shift. What is the Pythonic way of creating integer variables with fixed width (e.g. uint32, int16 etc.) that would overflow/shift accordingly?

Comment: There is the [fixedint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fixedint/0.1.2) library. They handle typical bit-fiddling and bitset operations.

Comment: fixedint looks pretty good! Thanks! I think that's a comment that should become an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the [fixedint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fixedint) library. The classes in that library are named in the following convention:

```
[Mutable][U]Int<N>
```

So for your two examples, the classes would be

```
#    C++                 Python fixedint
 std::uint32                 UInt32
 std::uint16                 UInt16
```

This supports things like bit-shifting, etc

```
>>> a = fixedint.UInt32(14)
>>> a
UInt32(14)
>>> a << 2
UInt32(56)
```

Comment: Another option is [nativetypes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nativetypes), which additionally supports floating-point values and custom type aliases.

Answer (score 3):

For interfacing with hardware we normally use the `struct` standard library - specifically `struct.pack` and `struct.unpack` not only are fixed widths handled but also endianess issues.  See the [python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) or [python  3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library manuals.

Once you have retrieved your data from your hardware and unpacked it if you are going to be performing any **heavy duty** mathematics on it you would usually assign it to [numpy](https://numpy.org/) data types which will:

1. Provide just about any operation that you could need,
2. Behave as expected for the data type
3. If you have lots of data stored in arrays or matrices provide vector methods for handling the data quickly & simply.

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.uint32(42)
print(x << 20)  # 44040192
print(x << 32)  # 180388626432 - Looks like it has been promoted
print(type(x << 32)) # numpy.int64 - it has
```

So **if** you are doing something such as reading a set of A-D readings from registers and then performing a lot of maths on them so as to produce a graph, etc. then this is fine **but** if you are reading a value from one register, doing some math, then writing the results back to a register you need to take care using anything like numpy.

Note that there is also the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) library available for interfacing with hardware *and DLLs* **but** it will always expect the values to be in "native" format - so, for example, if you are reading a 16 bit number from big endian hardware on a little endian machine then you will get problems.

Comment: That's a useful package to remember as well. Thanks!

Comment: how you do integer arithmetic with packs :-)

Comment: @wick - Unpack the data from the hardware, perform arithmetic, and _if needed_ try to pack, deal with any issues such as overflows then send _good_ packed data back to hardware.

Comment: @SteveBarnes aren't we losing all performance gains by doing all that? My thinking is performance being the whole point of using integers aligned with CPU registers...

Comment: @wick The question was about _correctly_ **interfacing** with hardware drivers not CPU performance. One of the mantras of the python world is to avoid premature optimisation. Python integers are not CPU aligned but **very** powerful and often fast enough.